# Which Join or Union to use?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL 2 tables for example (SSMS v18.8):

Table1

| Date | Name | Value | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-05 | Person | 1 | null |
| 2021-01-06 | Person | 2 | null |
| 2021-01-08 | Person | 3 | null |
| 2021-01-09 | Person | 4 | null |

Table2

| Date | Name | Value | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-05 | Person | null | a |
| 2021-01-07 | Person | null | b |

I am trying to combine these tables to get the desired outcome:

| Date | Name | Value | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-05 | Person | 1 | a |
| 2021-01-06 | Person | 2 | null |
| 2021-01-07 | Person | null | b |
| 2021-01-08 | Person | 3 | null |
| 2021-01-09 | Person | 4 | null |

However I have tried Union All and i am getting the following result:

```
SELECT DATE, NAME, VALUE, NULL AS REASON
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT DATE, NAME, NULL AS VALUE, REASON
FROM Table2
```

| Date | Name | Value | Reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-05 | Person | 1 | null |
| 2021-01-05 | Person | null | a |
| 2021-01-06 | Person | 2 | null |
| 2021-01-07 | Person | null | b |
| 2021-01-08 | Person | 3 | null |
| 2021-01-09 | Person | 4 | null |

I am assuming this will be very simple but thank you in advanced!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `full join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.DATE, t2.DATE) as DATE,
       COALESCE(t1.NAME, t2.NAME) as NAME,
       t1.VALUE, t2.REASON
FROM Table1 t1 FULL JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t1.NAME = t2.NAME AND
        t1.DATE = t2.DATE;
```

Comment: Thank you, Is the `Coalesce` crucial? I tried every join type initially. Full Join gives me:

| Date      |Name  |Value|Reason|
| --------  |----- |-----|----- |
| 2021-01-05|Person|1    |a      |
| 2021-01-06|Person|2    |null  |
| null|null|null |b     |
| 2021-01-08|Person|3    |null  |
| 2021-01-09|Person|4    |null  |

Comment: @DeanCohen . . . If you don't use `COALESCE()` you are likely to get `NULL` values -- which you probably don't want.

Comment: That is my first time coming across `Coalesce`, I have put it into my query and from what I can tell that has worked perfectly. Thank you! :)